# Unable to sent an email using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, tankauth

I have a codeigniter with tank auth configured.I was doing all the test and everything was running properly on my development server.I shiftwd all my codes to the productiom server and no activation email of tank auth is being sent.I used gmail cobfiguration in the email vodeingiter config and email was sent but to some emails its not being sent.Why im i unable to sent email using the default codeigniter settinga in the production server.please help

Comment: if email is not sending, then it must return some error please try `$this->email->print_debugger()` and let us know what is the error

Answer (score 0):

In the function where you sending you data afte completion of task

```
$email = 'email on which you want to send mail';
 $Subject = "Your subject message";
                        $smsg = null;
                        $smsg = 'yor message';

         $email_from = 'manishatutorsbureau@gmail.com';
                            $header = 'From: ' . $email_from . "\r\n" .
                                    'Reply-To: ' . $email_from . "\r\n" .
                                    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

                            // Start code for sending mail
                            mail($email, $Subject, $smsg, $header);
```